# Problemas con res.sendFile() express 4.14 Node.js 4.2

Tags: nodejs, express

Buenas. Llevo un par de días con un error. Os lo comunico por si alguien sabe porque sucede.

Tengo un proyecto `AngularJS v1.5.11` + `Node.js v4.2.6`
 (con `express v4.14.1` ) y al levanatarlo con `node server.js`  no me reconoce Angular.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo cuando lo ejecuto sin el Node.js (arastrandolo al navegador) Me funciona correctamente. Por eso he llegado a la conclusión que el error esta en el Express.

Mi sistema de carpetas es este::

- server.js
- node_modules/
- public/
- --- app/
- --- assets/
- --- index.html

> Codigo Server.js (actualizado)

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT||4000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

> Codigo index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="../server.js"></script>
    <script src="app/libs/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app/libs/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="app/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/config.js"></script>

    <script src="app/js/components/testText/test-text.module.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/components/testText/test-text.component.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/components/testText/test-text.template.html"></script>
  </head>
  <body >

    <div ng-view></div>
    hola

  </body>
</html>
```

Si alguien sabe que puedo hacer. Por favor no dudeis en comentar.

Comment: Te falta definir *assets* como un directorio **estático**: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));`.

Comment: Podrias ser un poco mas especifico?

Comment: Express **necesita saber qué directorio sevirá contenido estático**, es decir, imágenes, archivos css, js, etc. Y eso se hace **añadiendo un middleware** al servidor como te indico: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));`

Comment: No me ha funcionado. Para que funcione el `path` has de hacer un require `var path = require('path');`

Comment: pero no funciona. Gracias por tu interes.

Comment: Aunque no funcione para tu problema **es obligatorio hacerlo**, de lo contrario, **jamás podrás obtener archivos estáticos** del servidor. Actualiza tu pregunta y añade tu index.html.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53267/discussion-between-guzgarcia-and-pictorgames).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que express pueda enviar archivos estáticos **debes establecer el directorio** que contienen esos archivos. Esto se hace **mediante un middleware** como te indico a continuación:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/app')));
```

La línea anterior le dice a express que **todo entro de** `public/app` son archivos estáticos. En tu HTML, solo debes pedirlos mediante rutas relativas, en donde `/` equivale al directorio estático:

```
<script src="/server.js"></script>
<script src="/libs/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/libs/angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/js/config.js"></script>

<script src="/js/components/testText/test-text.module.js"></script>
<script src="/js/components/testText/test-text.component.js"></script>
<script src="/js/components/testText/test-text.template.html"></script>
```